# Why is CKModifyRecordsOperation to batch delete records in CloudKit not deleting records?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cloudkit, ckmodifyrecordsoperation

I have code to batch delete records from the private database in CloudKit, but it's not working. (I also noticed that the records I saved are not remaining.) I am using an actual iPhone 8 with an actual Apple ID I personally use, not a developer account. I get the same results with an iPhone 8 Simulator. I don't have this problem when I log in to iCloud with the same Apple ID as my developer account using iPhone 8 Simulator.

After answers to this post have not given me a solution, I think the most important thing about this problem is that it occurs when I use an Apple ID that is not my developer account. I tried it on two different Apple IDs that are not my developer account. Could it be a setting I'm overlooking somewhere?

None of the similar posts on stackoverflow solves this problem.

It looks like some of the records that the code is supposed to delete is actually deleted, but some are not. When I run the code again, there exists records still, but about one less the number as before.

Here is my code:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let splitViewController = window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
        let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController
        navigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem
        splitViewController.delegate = self

        deleteRecords()
        return true
    }

}

let privateDatabase = CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase

func deleteRecords() {

    print("deleteRecords()")

    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: DatabaseNameStrings.recordTypeAffirmation, predicate: predicate)

    privateDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) {

        (records: [CKRecord]?, error: Error?) in

        if error != nil {

            print(error as Any)

        } else {

            if let records = records {

                print("records.count=", records.count)

                let recordIDsToDelete = records.map { $0.recordID }
                print("recordIDsToDelete:")
                print(recordIDsToDelete)
                let operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: nil, recordIDsToDelete: recordIDsToDelete)
                operation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { savedRecords, deletedRecordIDs, error in
                    if error == nil {
                        print("Batch delete records!")
                        print("number of records deleted:", deletedRecordIDs?.count as Any)
                        printNumberOfRecords()
                    } else {
                        print(error as Any)
                    }
                }
                privateDatabase.add(operation)

            }

        }

    }
}

func printNumberOfRecords() {

    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: DatabaseNameStrings.recordTypeAffirmation, predicate: predicate)

    privateDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) {

        (records: [CKRecord]?, error: Error?) in

        if error != nil {

            print(error as Any)

        } else {

            if let records = records {

                print("Number of records in CloudKit=", records.count)

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Here is the output in the debug window from the first run of the code:

```
deleteRecords()
records.count= 93
recordIDsToDelete:
[<CKRecordID: 0x280bbcb00; recordName=B33A3F23-23D3-44C6-AEBC-86DD718DBB62, zoneID=...>, ... ]
Batch delete records!
number of records deleted: Optional(93)
Number of records in CloudKit= 67
```

Here is the output in the debug window from the second run of the code:

```
deleteRecords()
records.count= 92
recordIDsToDelete:
[<CKRecordID: 0x280080d00; recordName=BBA5B236-A036-4AC9-82E1-165D3B003E23, zoneID=...>, ... ]
Batch delete records!
number of records deleted: Optional(92)
Number of records in CloudKit= 52
```

When I use this code instead of deleteRecords() ...

```
func deleteRecordsOneAtATime() {

    print("deleteRecordsOneAtATime()")

    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: DatabaseNameStrings.recordTypeAffirmation, predicate: predicate)

    privateDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) {

        (records: [CKRecord]?, error: Error?) in

        if error != nil {

            print(error as Any)

        } else {

            if let records = records {

                print("records.count=", records.count)

                let recordIDsToDelete = records.map { $0.recordID }
                print("recordIDsToDelete:")
                print(recordIDsToDelete)

                for recordID in recordIDsToDelete {

                    privateDatabase.delete(withRecordID: recordID) {
                        (localRecordID: CKRecord.ID?, error: Error?) in
                        if error != nil {
                            print("error:\n", error as Any)
                        } else {
                            if localRecordID != nil {
                                print("localRecordID:", localRecordID as Any)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                printNumberOfRecords()

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

I get in the debug window:

```
deleteRecordsOneAtATime()
Number of records in CloudKit= 97
records.count= 97
recordIDsToDelete:
[<CKRecordID: 0x283622ec0; recordName=600B7BFE-04FE-4F63-BC4C-5AD1AE08908D, zoneID=...>, ... ]
localRecordID: Optional(<CKRecordID: 0x2821ff320; recordName=8E8CD0F0-FDF5-4CB9-B16C-5CF91C3503A2, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>)
localRecordID: Optional(<CKRecordID: 0x2821ff320; recordName=8E0A0816-1B05-4707-A4E7-C40762E68663, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>)
localRecordID: Optional(<CKRecordID: 0x28210b200; recordName=8E127624-F1D3-401E-ADF2-BB97354FCA98, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>)
...
Number of records in CloudKit= 87
localRecordID: Optional(<CKRecordID: 0x282108660; recordName=962639D1-83E6-40D2-A57D-F70ADCEBED08, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>)
localRecordID: Optional(<CKRecordID: 0x28210ff20; recordName=968D62AB-523E-464B-94B8-3C90E0382AB6, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>)
localRecordID: Optional(<CKRecordID: 0x28210faa0; recordName=96C92DD2-ED27-4FED-8320-44D03981B04F, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>)
localRecordID: Optional(<CKRecordID: 0x2821085a0; recordName=96A2D515-D3E7-475E-B609-8389DE4B88D1, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>)
```

Here is my latest code that still doesn't work:

```
func removeRecords() {

    print("removeRecords()")

    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: DatabaseNameStrings.recordTypeAffirmation, predicate: predicate)

    privateDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) {

        (records: [CKRecord]?, error: Error?) in

        if error != nil {

            print(error as Any)

        } else {

            if let records = records {

                print("records.count=", records.count)

                let recordIDsToDelete = records.map { $0.recordID }
                print("recordIDsToDelete:")
                print(recordIDsToDelete)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    if recordIDsToDelete.count > 50 {
                        let slice = Array(recordIDsToDelete[0 ..< 50])
                        let leftOver = Array(recordIDsToDelete[50 ... recordIDsToDelete.count-1])

                        privateDatabase.remove(recordsWith: slice) {
                            (result: Result<Void, Error>) in
                            print("result:", result)
                            switch result {
                            case .failure(let err):
                                print("failure")
                                print(err)
                            case .success(()):
                                print("success")
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    privateDatabase.remove(recordsWith: leftOver) {
                                        (result: Result<Void, Error>) in
                                        print("result:", result)
                                        switch result {
                                        case .failure(let err):
                                            print("failure")
                                            print(err)
                                        case .success(()):
                                            print("success")
                                        }
                                        print("type of result:", type(of: result))
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            print("type of result:", type(of: result))
                        }

                    } else {

                        privateDatabase.remove(recordsWith: recordIDsToDelete) {
                            (result: Result<Void, Error>) in
                            print("result:", result)
                            switch result {
                            case .failure(let err):
                                print("failure")
                                print(err)
                            case .success(()):
                                print("success")
                            }
                            print("type of result:", type(of: result))
                        }

                    }





                    privateDatabase.remove(recordsWith: recordIDsToDelete) {
                        (result: Result<Void, Error>) in
                        print("result:", result)
                        switch result {
                        case .failure(let err):
                            print("failure")
                            print(err)
                        case .success(()):
                            print("success")
                        }
                        print("type of result:", type(of: result))
                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

}

extension CKDatabase {
    func remove(
        recordsWith ids: [CKRecord.ID], completion: @escaping CompletionHandler<Void>) {
        let operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordIDsToDelete: ids)
        operation.qualityOfService = .userInitiated
        operation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { _, _, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("error:")
                print(error)
                if let err = error as? CKError, let time = err.retryAfterSeconds {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + time) {
                        self.remove(recordsWith: ids, completion: completion)
                    }
                } else {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                    print("CKDatabase.remove(_:_:) failed.")
                }
            } else {
                completion(.success(()))
                print("CKDatabase.remove(_:_:) succeeded.")
            }
        }
        self.add(operation)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code was deleting what it got from the perform query method. It's just that the perform query method was not returning the record ids from all the existing records.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes CloudKit will throw different errors at you, so you have to make sure you handle them, and trigger the call again if error contains `retryAfterSeconds`. Here, use this wrapper method for `CKDatabase` to handle the errors in the with very little effort. When calling any CloudKit API make sure to batch your requests to smaller chunks (ex. 100 items each).

```swift
extension CKDatabase {
    func remove(
        recordsWith ids: [CKRecord.ID], 
        completion: @escaping (Result<Void, Error>) -> Void
    ) {
        let operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordIDsToDelete: ids)
        operation.qualityOfService = .userInitiated
        operation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { _, _, error in
            if let error = error {
                if let err = error as? CKError, let time = err.retryAfterSeconds {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + time) {
                        self.remove(recordsWith: ids, completion: completion)
                    }
                } else {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
            } else {
                completion(.success(()))
            }
        }
        self.add(operation)
    }
}
```

Comment: There is not a type called CompletionHandler. What's the declaration of that closure?

Comment: oh I am sorry, this is a typealias I like to use. Its a closure that takes a Swifts `Result` value as parameter.

`typealias CompletionHandler<T> = (Result<T, Error>) -> Void`

Comment: It didn't work. I still have remaining records when I restart the app. The count of the records are less than the previous count. It looks like one or a few of the records were permanently deleted.

Comment: No. None. I checked by putting a print(error) statement after inside of the if let error = error statement loop. Now the count of records is even lower. It looks like more records were permanently deleted than usually before.

Comment: How do you check the argument of type (Result<T, Error>)? I couldn't use a == with it.

Comment: you would have to perform `switch` on the result to access the value. in the code sample I have provided `T` is `Void`.

Comment: I just tried it one more time, and it worked. All records are permanently deleted. I don't know what worked. Thank you.

Comment: since this is a asynchronous operation, are you sure the dependencies are not getting deallocated before the it finishes?

Comment: @DanielBrower awesome to hear that!

Comment: stack**overflow** is making wait two hours before it will allow me to award the bounty

Comment: What do you put as the argument for the failure case in the switch statement? case .failure(?)?

Comment: since your are trying to find out if its carrying a value, you assume that it is there so you name it as you want. eg: `case .failure(let error): print(error)`. to read more about Swift Result type, I encourage you to read this blog post: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/the-power-of-result-types-in-swift/

Comment: Ok. Thanks. That helps.

Comment: did you try to split the request into a smaller chunks? eq. try deleting 50 records at a time rather than the whole batch

Comment: I tried that. It still didn't work. I put the code I tried in my post.

Comment: I don't have a problem when I'm using CloudKit with my developer account that I use with my Xcode project.

Comment: so it only occurs while using different apple ids than yours? then we may be looking at completely different problem... but I have to say it is weird behaviour from the cloudkit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211821/discussion-between-daniel-brower-and-witek-bobrowski).

Answer (score 2):

Try these changes;

after

```
  let operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: nil, recordIDsToDelete: recordIDsToDelete)
```

add

```
  operation.database = privateDatabase
  operation.queuePriority = .veryHigh
  operation.configuration =  CKOperation.Configuration()
  operation.configuration.qualityOfService = .userInteractive
```

Then start the operation with;

```
  operation.start()
```

instead of;

```
  privateDatabase.add(operation)
```

Comment: try adding operation.isAtomic = true  This shouldn't be needed, but you might get a useful error message.

Comment: No. That didn't do it. I also tried code to delete one at a time. I updated the post with that information.

Comment: Does it matter if I'm not using my developer account to test CloudKit, but using an account I personally use?

Comment: note that the second "printNumberOfRecords" is not a valid call because the delete operations won't be finished when you call it. You have to wait until all the delete calls have finished their completion blocks before you call "printNumberOfRecords".

Comment: Yes. I noticed that the print statement executed early in the debug output.